# php using wamp server start up error

Tags: php, sql-server

i try to install moodle web software...i m using wamp server and sqlserver 2005 version.
i install php driver for php5.3.0 thread safe version..i just paste that php_sqlsrv_ts.dll driver file
into my php ext directory...i include this line extension=php_sqlsrv_ts.dll in my php.ini file...
now i restart my wampserver...i m getting this error...

PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match

get this error also in my apache log file

ADODB Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

please anybody help me..

Answer (score 0):

I also tried working with that server as well, and got errors.

Then I found XAMPP.

XAMPP is much more reliable and it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20060613 PHP compiled with module API=20090626

I think the module sounds like it was compiled with Visual Studio 6 and PHP was compiled with Visual Studio 9.

You should re-download the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098) extract it and use the php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll library. You will also need to update the php.ini file with

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll
```